# How to use SDL_TTF's outlines

Tags: sdl, ttf

This might be a basic question but googling isn't turning out anything useful:

How are we supposed to use TTF_SetFontOutline ? I know we're able to create an outline (and it looks alright) but since it's the same colour as the main font I don't see any practical usage for it.

I can't find any way to set the colour separately and rendering two font instances makes it very hard to line up.

So what is a typical usage case for it?

Answer (score 10):

You can acheive what you want by drawing the text with an outline in one color, and then drawing it without outline on top of that, in another color.

---

Here's an example of white text with a black outline from [the libsdl forum](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=22030&sid=80b8f05a81a02d01174a15141bfba2d5#22030):

```
#define OUTLINE_SIZE 2

/* load font and its outline */ 
font = TTF_OpenFont(font_path, font_size); 
font_outline = TTF_OpenFont(font_path, font_size); 
TTF_SetFontOutline(font_outline, OUTLINE_SIZE); 

/* render text and text outline */ 
SDL_Color white = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF}; 
SDL_Color black = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00}; 
SDL_Surface *bg_surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font_outline, text, black); 
SDL_Surface *fg_surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, text, white); 
SDL_Rect rect = {OUTLINE_SIZE, OUTLINE_SIZE, fg_surface->w, fg_surface->h}; 

/* blit text onto its outline */ 
SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(fg_surface, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND); 
SDL_BlitSurface(fg_surface, NULL, bg_surface, &rect); 
SDL_FreeSurface(fg_surface); 

/* we now have RGBA white text with black outline in bg_surface */
```

Answer (score 1):

The colour is set to be the same as the font, so it can't be used as you'd like it to be.

I'd suggest having a look at bitmap fonts, there's a tutorial [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/41_bitmap_fonts/index.php).

Alternatively, if you'd like to continue using SDL_TTF, you could look into generating a glyph atlas. I personally don't have much experience with this but it is explained in another question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/48139/81668).